# Do folder search times decrease with smaller files

Tags: search, powershell, filesystems, filesize, file-extension

If you have a larger folder tree with only files of `0-10Kb` in size, and you had the same tree and the same files, but the files were `10-100Mb` each. Would the search times be affected by the size of the files when searching for all files with a given extension?

E.g. Would the following PowerShell be affected?

```
dir C:\LargeFolderStructure -Filter '*.txt' -rec
```

Comment: Depends on the filesystem but in general I would say no

Comment: As Reda said, it depends. Depends on various factor like: file system(mentioned above), fragmentation, number of files(as dgomolka said), a way that your system index(store informations about) your files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the files should not impact the query time on the directory.

If you want to test it yourself check out the Measure-Command cmdlet.  It will show you the amount of time it takes to execute a command.

```
Measure-Command {dir C:\LargeFolderStructure -Filter '*.txt' -rec }
```